# c# Web service to handle repeating/multiple items

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I am new to using Webservice. I implemented a soap Post action to an external Company. Working great. I now want to start creating my own for people to interact with us. I have created the basic add service as all tutorial etc.

Now I want to create a service that you place orders from. Currently I just write the order to a text file with the PO nr as the file name. Got testing working with submitting just 1 item to it. But I want them to pass it with mutiple items on the call. Here is what I got now.

c#

```
   public struct OrderSystem
    {

        public string ResultMsg;
    }


[WebMethod(MessageName = "Submit Order", Description = "Submit Order")]
public OrderSystem Order(string Custnr,string POnr, string[] Item , int[] qty)
{ 
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
        new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\"+POnr+".txt"))
    {
                file.WriteLine(Custnr);
                file.WriteLine(POnr);

                for (int i =0; i< Item.Length; i++)
                {
                    file.WriteLine("LineItem" + i +Item[i] + " | "+qty[i]);
                }  
    }

    OrderSystem result;

        result.ResultMsg = "Complete";
        return (result);

}
```

Current XML way to call it. Not friendly for them to design a Call to me

```
POST /Orders.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/Submit Order"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Submit_x0020_Order xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Custnr>string</Custnr>
      <POnr>string</POnr>
      <Item>
        <string>string</string>
        <string>string</string>
      </Item>
      <qty>
        <int>int</int>
        <int>int</int>
      </qty>
    </Submit_x0020_Order>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How I want to make the xml call file to look at.

```
POST /Orders.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/Submit Order"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Submit_x0020_Order xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Custnr>000223</Custnr>
      <POnr>988590</POnr>
      <ItemList>
        <Item>
            <ItemNr>1</Item>
            <Item>ABC123</Item>
            <Qty>2</Qty>
        </Item>
                <Item>
            <ItemNr>2</Item>
            <Item>ASC123</Item>
            <Qty>45</Qty>
        </Item>
                <Item>
            <ItemNr>3</Item>
            <Item>XYZKKF</Item>
            <Qty>4</Qty>
        </Item>
                <Item>
            <ItemNr>4</Item>
            <Item>FGH789</Item>
            <Qty>6</Qty>
        </Item>

      </ItemList>

    </Submit_x0020_Order>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How Can I go about and Change my C# service to handle that XML file.

Thank you in advance
Regards

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't create new services using ASMX in 2018. It's been [deprecated for a couple of years already](https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/microsoft-says-asmx-web-services-are-a-%E2%80%9Clegacy-technology%E2%80%9D/). Use WCF or Web API.

The solution applies to all technologies. Simply create a class:

```
public class Item
{
    public string ItemNr { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

And let your service accept a list of that class.

Comment: And if you are trying new things perhaps a EF codefirst will help you to store the data in a Database instead of a file.

Comment: Than you for your Answer on this. I will be looking into WCF. I will be storing data into a DB. The Textfile is just for testing now. Possible that You can show me how to use that class in the example?